# scala: preferred way of using map function

Tags: scala

I prefer to apply map on a list as:

```
items.map( myItem => ...)
```

But I also see many examples as:

```
items.map { case MyItem(...) => ... }
```

So which one is idiomatic?

Comment: The second one is also convenient for cases like`items.map { case MyItem(elem1, elem2) => executeOn(elem2) }`. Kind of a `destructor` inside map, but in the end it'a a matter of taste / readabilty / convenience

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both are perfectly fine. The second one is just a convenient syntax sugar for

```scala
items.map { myItem =>
  myItem match {
    case MyItem(...) => ...
  }
}
```

If you don't need to do a `match` on `myItem`, then the first syntax is what you'd generally use.

Comment: So second one is meant for scenarios when we have some patternmatching involved...

Comment: Yeah it can be convenient if `myItem` is a tuple or a case class or really any situation where you'd want to pattern match to extract its contents and don't care about `myItem` as a whole